# Ist selbst ein Reflexivpronomen?

Tags: reflexive

Im Englischen werden Reflexivpronomen auch in Kontexten verwendet bei denen die Deutschen nicht benutzt werden.

> The author reads himself.
>
> Der Autor liest selbst.

Was ist **selbst** hier für eine Wortart. Ist es ein Reflexivpronomen? Ein Adverb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laut [Wiktionaryeintrag](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/selbst) ist `selbst` ein Demonstrativpronomen, das als Apposition benutzt wird.

`selbst` bezieht sich hier zwar auf das Subjekt `der Autor`. Es ist aber keine Rückbeziehung oder Teil des Verbs (reflexive Verben), sondern lediglich eine Verstärkung.

`selbst` kann ohne grammatikalische Probleme und ohne Verlust der Kernaussage in dem Satz weggelassen werden. Lediglich der verstärkende Charakter geht verloren.

Comment: Hast du eine etwas offiziellere Quelle? Normalerweise ist Wiktionary okay, aber in schwierigen Fällen hätte ich gern etwas "quelligeres".

Comment: Tja, der Duden hat `selbst` nicht online gestellt (oder deren Server hat irgendwelche Probleme).

Comment: @Emanuel 'selbe, selber, selbes' im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/selbe) -> Wortart: Pronomen ... Grammatik: Demonstrativpronomen --- 'selbst' im [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=selbst): Pronomen ... Herkunft: selb Dem.pron. --- Reicht dir das?

Comment: Des Weiteren, in [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrativpronomen): 'Das Demonstrativpronomen oder auch hinweisendes Fürwort ist eine Wortart, mit der der Sprecher auf einen Gesprächsgegenstand verweist, auf den man mit dem Finger zeigen kann' --- Beispiel: "Ich selbst" - *mit Finger auf mich selbst zeigend* - "habe den Kuchen gebacken." (Ja, demnach wäre das Personalpronomen *ich* auch ein Demonstrativpronomen...)

Comment: @Em1 ... ja an sich reicht mir das an offiziellen Sachen :). Aber die Definition von WIkipedia ist wirklich unmöglich "Ich sehe mich" , "Er gibt mir etwas"... ich kann auch hier mit dem Finger auf mich zeigen ohne das es komisch ist. Und wie du ja sagst. "Ich" ist dann auch ein DemPron... buh Wikipedia buh!!

Comment: @Emanuel For the record, [canoonet](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Demonstr.html): Mit den Demonstrativpronomen wird nachdrücklich auf ein Lebewesen, ein Ding, etwas Abstraktes oder einen Sachverhalt hingewiesen. --- Und der dazugehörige Untereintrag zu [selbst/selber](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Demonstr-selbst.html?MenuId=Word4243)